# why the program is failing for really long number?

Tags: java

i have written this piece of code, where you input any integer and it will give you the smallest prime number of that integer. 
but it appears to fail for really really long numbers. 
why is that , and how can i fix it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ExThree {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number: ");
        long num = sc.nextInt();
        boolean isPrime = false ; 
        long prime;
        if(num>0){
            for(prime=2; prime<num && !isPrime; prime=prime+1){
                if(num%prime==0){
                    isPrime=true;
                }
            }
            if(prime==num){
                prime=prime+1;
            }
            System.out.println(prime-1);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("bad input");        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For really really long number you need `BigInteger`

Comment: "appears to fail" is a very vague description of what happens, and "really really long numbers" is a very vague description of the cause. Give an example of the input and expected/actual output.

Comment: for 562612851654168 this program will fail for example

Comment: @Invader, for 562612851654168 you need to use `sc.nextLong`

Answer (score 1):

```
long num = sc.nextInt();
```

You're calling `nextInt()` which returns an int, so it will fail for numbers that are too large to store in an int. Java ints have a maximum value of 2147483647, so `nextInt()` will fail for numbers like that.

`Scanner.nextLong()` returns a long, which has a maximum value of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. That's larger than your sample input of 562,612,851,654,168. So you should be able to read numbers like that using `nextLong()`.

If you need to read in numbers larger than a long, look at using `BigInteger` and `Scanner.nextBigInteger()`.

Answer (score 0):

Long/Int have, of course, maximal values. If you want to use numbers higher than that, use BigInteger (read String from scanner, then create a new BigInteger from it).

Answer (score 0):

Use `sc.nextLong();` to get a Long variable.